# Windows Azure using Eucalyptus

Tags: azure, connection, cloud, eucalyptus

I'm using Eucalyptus and I want know if is there some way to use Windows Azure using Eucalyptus.

Thx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 'use Windows Azure using Eucalyptus' is a bit ambiguous, so I will answer a couple of questions:

1. Can I run Eucalyptus on VMs inside Windows Azure? Not easily. Eucalyptus requires multicast support, which is not available in Windows Azure or in AWS.
2. Does Eucalyptus support the Windows Azure API such that I can point an Azure client at Eucalyptus and have it work? No, Eucalyptus does not support the Windows Azure API at this point. That isn't to say it will never support that API, but it currently does not.

I'm a developer on Eucalyptus, btw.